# Selenium automation test runs very slowly compared to manual testing

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

Something very odd is happening while running the automation. The automation fills a form and then clicks a button which sends a request to the server and awaits the reply. The timeout for the request is set to 4 minutes and the test keeps failing because of the timeout. So far makes sense.

The odd thing is that when I do the same test manualy (using the mouse and keyboard), the browser gets the response back after only 30 seconds top (tested several times).

What could be the reason for this difference between the automated test and the equivalent manual one?

Nugget packages installed and used:

- Selenium.Support 2.53.1
- Selenium.WebDriver 3.0.1

Comment: Please share the automation code + the HTML code/website which you are trying to automate.